# ¿Cuál es el nombre del adorno navideño que se ve en la foto?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, españa, sustantivos

[image]

Lo que se ve en la imagen es mi monitor del trabajo con un adorno navideño al que suelo denominar *[espumillón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Gg86TKd)* o *[guirnalda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JrWBIV2)*, según cómo me dé. Sin embargo, en sus definiciones no encuentro realmente nada que diga que la palabra se refiera a este adorno concreto. Lo más parecido es la primera acepción de *guirnalda*:

> 1. f. Corona abierta, tejida de flores, hierbas o ramas, con que se ciñe la cabeza.

En España, ¿cuál es pues el nombre exacto para referirse a este adorno?

Comment: Para mi es una _guirnalda_ pero veo que preguntas solo para España

Comment: Yo siempre le he llamado *guirnalda* a eso, aunque también he oído *espumillón*. En word reference la acepción de espumillón si encaja: http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/espumill%C3%B3n

Comment: **espumillón** *Tela de seda, muy doble, a manera de tercianela.* ¿Qué rayos significa "muy doble"?

Comment: @blonfu lo mejor es la definición de tercianela: "Gro de cordoncillo muy grueso". Ni sabía que la palabra "gro" existía.

Comment: @DGaleano aquí también se le suele llamar "guirnalda", pero la definición del DLE me hizo dudar...

Comment: @walen Me  ha pasado exactamente lo mismo, he ido encadenando definiciones

Comment: @blonfu La definición ha cambiado, pero en el DLE hasta 1984 la definición de **engandujo** era: "Hilo retorcido que cuelga de una franja que recibe el mismo nombre".

Comment: Usan espumillón en Leroy Merlin: http://www.leroymerlin.es/productos/decoracion_navidena/guirnaldas_y_espumillon.html
Guirnalda en IKEA: http://www.ikea.com/es/es/catalog/products/00355294/

Comment: @AlexBcn interesante el artículo del Leroy que dice "guirnalda de espumillón". :-D Al final las dos van a ser válidas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Una vez más la RAE sale al rescate. He mantenido la siguiente conversación con la RAE:

> [[Tuit mío]](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/943461159260258304): Buscando en el DLE "guirnalda" o "espumillón" no encuentro acepciones que identifiquen a este adorno navideño. ¿Tiene algún otro nombre o hay alguna definición pendiente de agregar a estas voces?
>
> [[Tuit RAE]](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/943461830239883264): Ya está previsto incluir una nueva acepción de esta voz que refleje el objeto de adorno navideño actual.
>
> [[Tuit mío]](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/943466011155681281): ¿Con "esta voz" se refieren a "guirnalda" o a "espumillón"?
>
> [[Tuit RAE]](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/943468008831373312): A «espumillón».

Así pues, parece que ***espumillón*** es el término correcto, el cual contará en breve con una acepción al respecto del adorno navideño (aunque parece que en la [versión 23.1](http://dle.rae.es/?t=/docs/aviso.html) de 2017 del DLE no ha tenido tiempo de entrar).

Comment: Yo creo que en realidad Charlie pertenece a la RAE y está infiltrado acá. Y a veces nos filtra información.

Comment: @MauricioMartinez y la conversación de arriba con la RAE es entonces una conversación conmigo mismo. :-D

Answer (score 3):

En México se le conoce como [escarcha navideña](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=escarcha%20navide%C3%B1a&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0-_idoZjYAhWJ3YMKHbyuBTYQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=949), y literalmente así la puedes pedir en tiendas o incluso [en línea](https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.mx/MLM-604888194-escarcha-navidena-_JM).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

En Chile se llaman "guirnaldas" y nadie dejaría de llamarlas así por no aparecer con tal nombre en el diccionario.

Como a mí me parecen bufandas de plumas de *burlesque*, también conocidas como [boas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boa_(prenda)), voy a sugerir (sólo como juego de palabras, por supuesto):

> **[boa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5hjAT8A)**
>
> Del lat. *boa*.
>
> 2. m. o f. Prenda femenina de piel o pluma y en forma de serpiente, para abrigo o adorno del cuello. U. menos c. m.

[image: boa (prenda)]

(Me consta que no respondo la pregunta).